# How to Customize an ERC721 token to act as Software License?

Tags: nft, erc-721

Hello i'm thinking about **how could i change an ERC721** to prevent people form **transferring** it for a price under a certain amount (the buying price), of course i need to change the standard and it will not be sellable on Marketplace, but it doesn't matter.

The aim is to let it act as a software license but with a restriction to the selling.

There's a way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can.
try this please.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC721/SafeERC721.sol";

contract MyToken is SafeERC721 {
  uint public minimumSalePrice;

  constructor(uint _minimumSalePrice) public {
    minimumSalePrice = _minimumSalePrice;
  }

  function setMinimumSalePrice(uint _minimumSalePrice) public {
    minimumSalePrice = _minimumSalePrice;
  }

  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _tokenId) public {
    require(_to != address(0), "ERC721: transfer to the zero address");
    require(_tokenId != 0, "ERC721: transfer of zero token");
    require(isApprovedOrOwner(_from, _tokenId), "SafeERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved");
    require(_to != _from, "SafeERC721: transfer to self");

    // Check if the proposed sale price is equal to or greater than the minimum sale price
    uint price = getPrice(_tokenId);
    require(price >= minimumSalePrice, "MyToken: sale price is below the minimum sale price");

    super._transferFrom(_from, _to, _tokenId);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is this SafeERC721 standard? i cannot find it in openzeppelin repo

Comment: You can browse the full list of contracts in the OpenZeppelin library by going to the following link:

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/tree/master/contracts

Comment: bro... don't use Chat gpt to answer question... they are wrong. please stop

Comment: I apologize for the mistake.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).